# Randomness and small circuits complexity classes

Tags: circuit-complexity, randomized-algorithms

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a complexity class and $\textrm{BP-}\mathcal{C}$ be the randomized counterpart of $\mathcal{C}$ defined as $\textrm{BPP}$ with respect to $\textrm{P}$. More formally we provide polynomially many random bit and we accept an input iff the probability to accept is over $\frac{2}{3}$.

It is known that for non-uniform circuits class we have $\textrm{BPAC}^0=\textrm{AC}^0$:

> Miklós Ajtai, Michael Ben-Or: A Theorem on Probabilistic Constant Depth Computations STOC 1984: 471-474

Are generalizations of this theorem known ? For instance, do we know if $\mathrm{BPNC}^1=\mathrm{NC}^1$ (still in the non-uniform setting)? This last question seems somehow non trivial to me since it seems plausible that for instance $s,t\textrm{-Connectivity}$ is in $\textrm{BPNC}^1$.

A relevant post on the subject: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35184/use-of-randomness-in-constant-parallel-time

Comment: What drives your hunch on connectivity?

Comment: Are you asking about *uniform* circuit classes? It’s fairly obvious that *nonuniform* classes like $\mathrm{NC^1}$ are closed under the BP operator.

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac it seems non completly impossible that we can simulate a random walk in BPNC1. A standard randomized algorithm for s,t-con follow. Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I change the post to clarify that I do talk about non-uniform class. I don't see how it is obvious, the proof of Ajtai and Ben-Or is not long and not very difficult but not obvious to me. Maybe I missing a point somehow ?

Comment: Just use the same argument as for P/poly. You only need the majority function, which is definable in $\mathrm{TC^0\subseteq NC^1}$. (Ajtai and Ben-Or need more work as majority is *not* available in $\mathrm{AC^0}$.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are perfectly right. For every non-unifom circuit class above $\textrm{TC}^0$ we have $\textrm{BP}-\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}$. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Seems you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I voted to close as not research-level. Clearly, I shouldn’t simultaneously do that, and post an answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Ah, I see. I think it's borderline; it's obviously not a *research* question, but it was clearly asked in earnest by someone with some research experience in complexity, who was simply misled by trying to extend Ajtai-Ben-Or rather than using the more straightforward approach.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Given that this has gathered 5 upvotes, it may not be the general consensus that having an answer written down is entirely worthless.  Alternatively, we may move that to Math SE.

Comment: All right, then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most nonuniform complexity classes—$\mathrm{NC^1}$ included—are closed under the $\mathrm{BP}$ operator by the same argument as $\mathrm{BPP\subseteq P/poly}$: using the Chernoff–Hoeffding bound, the probability of error can be reduced below $2^{-n}$ by running $O(n)$ instances of the circuit with independent random bits in parallel, and taking a majority vote; then by the union bound, a sequence of random bits gives the correct result for *all* $2^n$ inputs of length $n$ simultaneously with nonzero probability, and in particular, there *exists* such a sequence. We can hardwire it into the circuit.

This argument applies to any class of circuits that is closed under taking majority of $O(n)$ parallel copies of a circuit, and fixing input gates to constants. In practice, this means any decent nonuniform class above $\mathrm{TC^0}$, as majority is computable in $\mathrm{TC^0}$.

The proof is more complicated for $\mathrm{AC^0}$, because this class does *not* compute the majority function. (While I haven’t seen the Ajtai and Ben-Or paper, I’d guess they use some sort of approximate majority.)